# How do I fix "Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase RealTime Database to read and store data. When I try to read data from a specific node the app crashes and throughs a logcat exeption. When I look at my source code everything seems fine and in reality there is a problem.

This is the LogCat.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wireworks.moreeo, PID: 27550
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBoolean(CustomClassMapper.java:417)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(CustomClassMapper.java:292)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:215)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:604)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at tasks_package.ChoresFragment$4.onDataChange(ChoresFragment.java:454)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6892)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
```

I am trying to read

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chores")
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.keepSynced(true);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                chores.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot sn : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chores chor = sn.getValue(Chores.class);

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    long current_millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
                            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    final String todaysdate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                    if (chor.getTaskid() != null) {
                        if (chor.getDate().equals(todaysdate) && current_millis < chor.getTimeinmillisecs() &&
                                !chor.isIschecked()) {
                            chores.add(chor);
                            todaystaskkk.setText("(" + chores.size() + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }

                Collections.reverse(chores);
                checktasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

My Class used

```
public class Chores {

    private String Date;
    private String Endingdate;
    private String Endingtime;
    private boolean Ischecked;
    private boolean Isnote;
    private String Task;
    private String Taskdescription;
    private String Taskid;
    private String Time;
    private long Timeinmillisecs;
    private boolean Involvesapps;

    public Chores() {

    }

    public Chores(String date, String endingdate, String endingtime, boolean ischecked, boolean isnote, String task, String taskdescription, String taskid, String time, long timeinmillisecs, String involvesapps) {
        Date = date;
        Endingdate = endingdate;
        Endingtime = endingtime;
        Ischecked = ischecked;
        Isnote = isnote;
        Task = task;
        Taskdescription = taskdescription;
        Taskid = taskid;
        Time = time;
        Timeinmillisecs = timeinmillisecs;
        Involvesapps = involvesapps;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getEndingdate() {
        return Endingdate;
    }

    public void setEndingdate(String endingdate) {
        Endingdate = endingdate;
    }

    public String getEndingtime() {
        return Endingtime;
    }

    public void setEndingtime(String endingtime) {
        Endingtime = endingtime;
    }

    public boolean isIschecked() {
        return Ischecked;
    }

    public void setIschecked(boolean ischecked) {
        Ischecked = ischecked;
    }

    public boolean isIsnote() {
        return Isnote;
    }

    public void setIsnote(boolean isnote) {
        Isnote = isnote;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return Task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        Task = task;
    }

    public String getTaskdescription() {
        return Taskdescription;
    }

    public void setTaskdescription(String taskdescription) {
        Taskdescription = taskdescription;
    }

    public String getTaskid() {
        return Taskid;
    }

    public void setTaskid(String taskid) {
        Taskid = taskid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public long getTimeinmillisecs() {
        return Timeinmillisecs;
    }

    public void setTimeinmillisecs(long timeinmillisecs) {
        Timeinmillisecs = timeinmillisecs;
    }

    public String getInvolvesapps() {
        return Involvesapps;
    }

    public void setInvolvesapps(String involvesapps) {
        Involvesapps = involvesapps;
    }
}
```

What might be the problem kindly help me?
[image]

Comment: @JimmyWire change your class you have problem with `involveapps`. I've provided you code for class

Comment: At which line of code does that error occur?

Comment: @AlexMamo Chores chor = sn.getValue(Chores.class)

Comment: Are you sure that `Ischecked`, `Isnote` and `Involvesapps`, all are holding boolean values inside all children?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's because he is looking those value inside child where has he need to find those values inside child of child

Comment: @AlexMamo Like I said when I look at the source code everything seems fine but in reality there is a problem.

Comment: Are you sure that Ischecked, Isnote and Involvesapps, all are holding boolean values inside all children?

Comment: @AlexMamo What do you mean by this?

Comment: Check all children and see if all of them hold boolean values.

Comment: @AlexMamo Back in the database all the children nodes return a boolean

Comment: Most likely you have a boolean one, hence that error.

Comment: @AlexMamo Let me check my source code again

Comment: That's about the source code, it's about what you have in the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo The issue was in the for loop retrieving the data from the database. I've solved the issue thanks for your help.

Comment: @JimmyWire Can you post an answer showing how you changed the code from your question to solve the problem? Stack Overflow is about building a knowledge base together, and seeing how you solved the problem may help others in the future.